# how to pass different enum types to a method?

Tags: java, enums, generics

I have a method which takes an enum and uses it in some fashion. The issue is that I have many different enum types and am not what acceptable practice is to pass an enum to a method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean you have a bunch of different enum classes that mean separate things, and that you want to pass them into one method.

To do that, use a [marker interface](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=marker+interface+effective+java&source=bl&ots=yXLkLen_S_&sig=SN0fj5wfJDFK6cxOIyqssZs_RGw&hl=en&ei=Q7Y0TYGjFZKmsQP33rDSBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false):

```
public interface SpecialEnumType {
}
```

then:

```
public enum MySpecialEnumType implements SpecialEnumType {
  ...
}

public enum AnotherSpecialEnumType implements SpecialEnumType {
  ...
}
```

Now your method will accept a parameter of type `SpecialEnumType`:

```
public doSomething(SpecialEnumType specialEnumType) {
  ...
}
```

Having done that, you can do:

```
obj.doSomething(MySpecialEnumType.SomeThing);
obj.doSomething(AnotherSpecialEnumType.SomethingElse);
```

In general, it's perfectly alright to use an enum as a parameter type for a method argument.

**UPDATE**

I've used this pattern while integrating with third-party API's. For example, a little while ago I had to integrate with different shipping providers. To do this, I provided a general interface that allowed the developer to send in shipping information (like the addresses, packages, weights, packing options, etc.). If you wanted to implement integration with a new provided, all you needed to do was implement the interface.

Now each shipping provider had its own set of options. Before using marker interfaces, I had a single enum which contained all the options (of all the different shipping providers). This is obviously hard to maintain. But I couldn't split the enums into different classes because the interface specified a specific type of enum for the method arguments.

Using a marker interface, I was able to get around this problem. I created an interface called `ShippingProviderOption`. Then for each provider, I extended the interface and created an enum, with the specific options for that provider. This way I was able to separate out the options, but still present a common interface.

As far as code is concerned (greatly simplified and somewhat contrived, for demonstration purposes):

```
public interface ShippingProviderOption {
}

public enum UPSOption implements ShippingProviderOption {
    ...
}

public enum FedexOption implements ShippingProviderOption {
    ...
}

public interface ShippingProvider {

   public ShippingResponse ship(ShippingProviderOption option);
}

public class UPSProvider implements ShippingProvider {

   @Override
   public ShippingResponse ship(ShippingProviderOption option) {

       if(option == UPSOption.PackageType) {
          ...
       }
   }       
}

public class FedexProvider implements ShippingProvider {

   @Override
   public ShippingResponse ship(ShippingProviderOption option) {

       if(option == FedexOption.PickupType) {
          ...
       }
   }       
}
```

Now in my actual implementation, I have a few methods in the marker interface. So it doesn't really even have to be a marker interface; it can contain methods.

Comment: Intersting, could you post a small code sample  of how the passed value could be used?

Comment: It does have to be a marker interface. The interface can have methods which would help usage.

Comment: For extra type safety: `public <E extends Enum<E> & SpecialEnumType>void doSomething(E e)`

Comment: @finnw Thanks for the comment - I've wanted to do something like that, but didn't know how.

Comment: I am thknig of something similar, but I have it all my enums as inner enums of a single class, so they are all in the same file and each of these enums are to partition a set of numbers or codes without duplication. The issue i am facing with using an interface is that all my enums I need to call getName() on and I dont know how to do that without specifically casting to its real enum type. I may have to expose getName through the interface ?

Comment: @finnw, how does that add extra type-safety ?

Comment: @mafalda Yes, your interface would expose a `getName()` method and your enum would implement that method.

Comment: I see where the type safety comes in - you are generic method where formal parameter is an enum AND implements SpecialEnumType, so method wont accidentally accept someother class that implements SpecialEnumType

Comment: I tried this in c#, but when I use the : to indicate that it implements the interface, it thinks I'm defining a data type for the enum.
Am I just stuck?

Comment: @Michael, you might want to take a look at [this](http://elegantcode.com/2008/07/30/marker-interfaces-and-c-attributes/). It's from a few years ago, but it seems to encourage using attributes over marker interfaces.

Comment: @Vivin, are you saying I may be able to use an attribute on the enum, rather than an interface to be able to send any enum marked with that attribute to the target method?

Comment: @Michael I think so. I'm not that familiar with C# (I have novice-level experience!). The blog I linked to has more information.